# Using apache atlas as data catalog for snowflake

Tags: snowflake-schema, apache-atlas

I have snowflake as a data warehouse and want to use Apache atlas as a data catalog and lineage tool.
I went through the details but not sure it can be used with snowflake.
Is it possible to connect with a snowflake?

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I work for Snowflake.*

It is not possible, at this time, to use Atlas as the catalog. You can, however, use a [Hive Metastore](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-external-hive.html) with Snowflake. I have not tried to use things like the [Atlas Hook](https://atlas.apache.org/1.2.0/Hook-Hive.html) but perhaps that might be an option.